# How to only get dataset when run task synchronously and get dataset items APIFY

Tags: apify

I'm trying test with API run task synchronously and get dataset items APIFY and received json as follow:

```
 "2010HUNT1510": "A",
  "COSLUCKY15": "B",
  "CCB30K1015": "C",
  "CCB80K1015": "D",
  "#error": false,
  "#debug": {
    "requestId": "rSYcYoSkJkUB0Vu",
    "url": "url",
    "loadedUrl": "url",
    "method": "GET",
    "retryCount": 0,
    "errorMessages": [],
    "statusCode": 200
  }
```

I want only to show data and not include key "#error" and "#debug".
How can I resolve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a `&clean=1` parameter to your URL.